# Importing the `this` module?

Tags: python

Typing the following in a a Python shell does not produce an error:

```
from this import *
```

What is the `this` module?

Comment: Try `import this` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is the [`zen of python`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) written by Tim Peters

```
>>> from this import *
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
.....
>>> d
{'A': 'N', 'C': 'P', 'B': 'O', 'E': 'R', 'D': 'Q', 'G': 'T', 'F': 'S', 'I': 'V', 'H': 'U', 'K': 'X', 'J': 'W', 'M': 'Z', 'L': 'Y', 'O': 'B', 'N': 'A', 'Q': 'D', 'P': 'C', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'U': 'H', 'T': 'G', 'W': 'J', 'V': 'I', 'Y': 'L', 'X': 'K', 'Z': 'M', 'a': 'n', 'c': 'p', 'b': 'o', 'e': 'r', 'd': 'q', 'g': 't', 'f': 's', 'i': 'v', 'h': 'u', 'k': 'x', 'j': 'w', 'm': 'z', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'n': 'a', 'q': 'd', 'p': 'c', 's': 'f', 'r': 'e', 'u': 'h', 't': 'g', 'w': 'j', 'v': 'i', 'y': 'l', 'x': 'k', 'z': 'm'}
>>> c
'!'
```

And why would `from this import *` raise an error?

Using the above syntax simply merges `this` module's namespace into current namespace.

```
>>> import this
>>> dir(this)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'c', 'd', 'i', 's']
```

Also try:

```
import antigravity
```

Comment: A bit of history: http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html

Comment: Wait, what is `d` and `c`? Are there any others? Where is this documented?

Comment: @Randomblue you can view all of it's attributes by using `dir`: `import this;dir(this)`